# Make groups for each two sequential unique values

Tags: r

How can you number groups only once... and with repetition?

I have the following:

```
vehicle stop_time
Truck53 0:16:34
Truck53 0:18:06
Truck12 0:12:04
Truck12 0:16:32
Truck12 0:17:40
Truck65 0:13:22
Truck65 0:14:38
Truck65 0:15:43
Truck35 0:14:17
Truck35 0:17:37
Truck35 0:20:31
Truck39 0:15:04
Truck39 0:19:45
Truck39 0:22:10
Truck99 0:16:12
Truck59 0:17:44
Truck59 0:20:39
```

But, only 2 trucks can leave at a time, so I have to give them a wave id by repeatedly counting off once for every 2 trucks:

```
vehicle stop_time wave_id
Truck53 0:16:34 1
Truck53 0:18:06 1
Truck12 0:12:04 1
Truck12 0:16:32 1
Truck12 0:17:40 1
Truck65 0:13:22 2
Truck65 0:14:38 2
Truck65 0:15:43 2
Truck35 0:14:17 2
Truck35 0:17:37 2
Truck35 0:20:31 2
Truck39 0:15:04 3
Truck39 0:19:45 3
Truck39 0:22:10 3
Truck99 0:16:12 3
Truck59 0:17:44 4
Truck59 0:20:39 4
```

Comment: Your question was much better without the images and instead with text as in [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47560774/2), my advice is to rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
uv <- unique(df$vehicle)

df$wave_id <- ((seq_along(uv) + 1) %/% 2)[match(df$vehicle, uv)]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>    vehicle stop_time wave_id
> 1  Truck53   0:16:34       1
> 2  Truck53   0:18:06       1
> 3  Truck12   0:12:04       1
> 4  Truck12   0:16:32       1
> 5  Truck12   0:17:40       1
> 6  Truck65   0:13:22       2
> 7  Truck65   0:14:38       2
> 8  Truck65   0:15:43       2
> 9  Truck35   0:14:17       2
> 10 Truck35   0:17:37       2
> 11 Truck35   0:20:31       2
> 12 Truck39   0:15:04       3
> 13 Truck39   0:19:45       3
> 14 Truck39   0:22:10       3
> 15 Truck99   0:16:12       3
> 16 Truck59   0:17:44       4
> 17 Truck59   0:20:39       4
> ```

What this does:

1. With `unique(df$vehicle)` you create a vector of the unique truck id's.
2. With `((seq_along(uv) + 1) %/% 2)` you group the truck in groups of two trucks (and just one truck for the last group): `1 1 2 2 3 3 4`
3. With `match(mydf$vehicle, uv)` you create a vector of positions of the previous vector.
4. By indexing the vector from step 2 with the vector of step 3, you create a grouping vector with the same length of number of rows of `df`